# Whitespaces and line in BYacc

Tags: parsing, yacc

Hy guys.

What do you think about these two rules to parse whitespaces and to recognize the different lines of the file I must translate?

1.

```
line: NEW_LINE {$$ = System.lineSeparator();}
      | line NEW_LINE {$$ = $1 + System.lineSeparator();}

where:
NEW_LINE = \r\n|\n|\r   in Jflex
```

2.

```
whitespace: WHITESPACE {$$ = " ";}
            | whitespace WHITESPACE {$$ = $1 + " ";}

where:
WHITESPACE = [ \t]        in Jflex
```

Are they correct? Thanks of all

Answer (score 1):

```
line: NEW_LINE {$$ = System.lineSeparator();}
    | line NEW_LINE {$$ = $1 + System.lineSeparator();}
```

> where:

```
NEW_LINE = \r\n|\n|\r   in Jflex
```

If you don't really care about multliple newlines, as this grammar suggests, collect them all in the lexer:

```
NEW_LINE = (\r\n|\n|\r)+ return NEW_LINE;
```

and not in the parser:

```
line : NEW_LINE { $$ = System.lineSeparator(); }
```

Whitespace normally includes line terminators, unless they are significant in your grammar, which they seem to be, but also formfeeds:

```
WHITESPACE  [ \t\f]
```

and again it is much more efficient to collect it all in the lexer rather than the parser:

```
WHITESPACE  [ \t\f]+

whitespace: WHITESPACE { $$ = strdup(yytext); }
```

Note that this has to be `free()`-d whenever it reappears as `$1,` `$2,` etc, and isn't copied directly to `$$.`

But then usually whitespace doesn't appear in the grammar at all, it is just ignored by the lexer:

```
WHITESPACE  [ \t\f]+ ;
```

unless again you really really need it in the grammar. This is pretty unlikely. You should just be able to work with the non-whitespace tokens the lexer returns to you.